# BootStrap - List Hover change Color - Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, nav

I am trying to change the **background color** and **Text Color** of the navigation bar links on hover however I cannot get it to work. No matter what I do there doesnt seem to be any effect.

I have never had a problem when using Pure CSS, but its just mostly with Bootstrap I'm having this problem

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Soni's Computer Repair</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <center>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="Final.png"/></a>
                    </center>
                </div>

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>


                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container">
                <h6 class="text-center">Copyright &copy; Soni Computer Repairs</h6>
                <p class="text-center">www.SoniRepairs.com</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav, .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    margin-top: -15px;
}

.navbar-nav li {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.navbar .navbar-inverse .navbar-fixed-top > li > a:hover {
    color: cyan;
}


.navbar-brand {
  float: none;
}

.navbar-center {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    height:100%;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.logo img {
    height:80px;
    margin-top: -15px;

}

.logo {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

    .navbar-nav{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:none;
        margin-top: 10px;

    }

    .container img {
        height:50px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: -15px;
    }

    .navbar-brand {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .navbar > .container {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .collapse.navbar-collapse {
        width: auto;
        clear: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle.

Comment: @SharathDaniel https://jsfiddle.net/3ge0b6nr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You html code shows `navbar-static-top`

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"></div>
```

and in your css you are using `.navbar-fixed-top`

```
.navbar .navbar-inverse .navbar-fixed-top > li > a:hover {
    color: cyan;
}
```

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3ge0b6nr/1/

Change your code to

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top li > a:hover {
    color: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Sample jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/fbmrp8hk/) based on your code.

Just add this `css code` to your `css` :

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: red;
}    
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:active,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{
  color: green;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Just change it to which color you want.